# neovim: pwntools process automatically stops when trying to invoke interactive shell

Tags: python, binary, shellcode, pwntools

I'm using python pwntools.
I'm using ***python 3.10.x***

This line of code should open a shell for me:
`io.interactive()`

But while running this file from vim using
`!./%` it doesn't open the shell doesn't invoke as it was supposed to be. The process stops contrarily.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pwn import *

elf = context.binary = ELF("house_of_force")
libc = elf.libc
 
gs = '''
continue
'''
def start():
    if args.GDB:
        return gdb.debug(elf.path, gdbscript=gs)
    else:
        return process(elf.path)
 
# Select the "malloc" option, send size & data.
def malloc(size, data):                                                                                                                                                                                            
    io.send("1")                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    io.sendafter("size: ", f"{size}")                                                                                                                                                                              
    io.sendafter("data: ", data)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    io.recvuntil("> ")                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# Calculate the "wraparound" distance between two addresses.                                                                                                                                                       
def delta(x, y):                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return (0xffffffffffffffff - x) + y                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
io = start()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# This binary leaks the address of puts(), use it to resolve the libc load address.                                                                                                                                
io.recvuntil("puts() @ ")                                                                                                                                                                                          
libc.address = int(io.recvline(), 16) - libc.sym.puts                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# This binary leaks the heap start address.                                                                                                                                                                        
io.recvuntil("heap @ ")                                                                                                                                                                                            
heap = int(io.recvline(), 16)                                                                                                                                                                                      
io.recvuntil("> ")                                                                                                                                                                                                 
io.timeout = 0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# =============================================================================                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# =-=-=- EXAMPLE -=-=-=                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# The "heap" variable holds the heap start address.                                                                                                                                                                
log.info(f"heap: 0x{heap:02x}")                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# Program symbols are available via "elf.sym.<symbol name>".                                                                                                                                                       
log.info(f"target: 0x{elf.sym.target:02x}")                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# The malloc() function chooses option 1 from the menu.                                                                                                                                                            
# Its arguments are "size" and "data".                                                                                                                                                                             
malloc(24, b"Y"*24)                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# The delta() function finds the "wraparound" distance between two addresses.                                                                                                                                      
log.info(f"delta between heap & main(): 0x{delta(heap, elf.sym.main):02x}")

# =============================================================================

io.interactive()
```

***Error:***

```
/home/pegasus/Documents/Courses/HeapLAB-main/house_of_force/./exploit.py:19: BytesWarning: Text is not bytes; assuming ASCII, no guarantees. See https://docs.pwntools.com/#bytes
  io.sendafter("size: ", f"{size}")
/home/pegasus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/tube.py:813: BytesWarning: Text is not bytes; assuming ASCII, no guarantees. See https://docs.pwntools.com/#bytes
  res = self.recvuntil(delim, timeout=timeout)
/home/pegasus/Documents/Courses/HeapLAB-main/house_of_force/./exploit.py:21: BytesWarning: Text is not bytes; assuming ASCII, no guarantees. See https://docs.pwntools.com/#bytes
  io.recvuntil("> ")
[*] delta between heap & main(): 0xfffffffffebd9816
[*] Switching to interactive mode
[*] Stopped process '/home/pegasus/Documents/Courses/HeapLAB-main/house_of_force/house_of_force' (pid 7496)
```